# PHP Constructor Not Called Upon Instantiation

Tags: php, oop, constructor

My PHP class constructor appears to not be getting called when the class is initiated.  This is what my constructor looks like:

```
public function __contruct()
{
  $GLOBALS['page_content'] .= "<p>Constructor entered.</p>\r\n";

  try
  {
    $this->ConstructorBase();
  }
  catch ( Exception $e )
  {
    throw new Exception(
      "Error in ".__FILE__."(".__LINE__."): Constructor failed.",
      CLoginError::ERROR_CANNOT_INSTANTIATE, $e );
  }
}
```

Later in the same file, in the global scope, I attempt to instantiate the class:

```
$Login = new CLogin();
```

However, when I inspect `$GLOBALS['page_content']`, after instantiating the class, it is empty, as if the constructor was never called.  What is odd is that I can call public member functions.  If you want to see it, the full source is posted here:

http://pastebin.com/D95YnUmS

Comment: Also GLOBALS and exceptions in constructors are bad practice

Comment: Exceptions are not bad practices at all in constructors, it is actually recommended in any cases to trigger_error and is the only valid mechanism to catch errors that occur while creating objects. I do agree though on the GLOBALS, do not use GLOBALS anywhere... bad bad bad practice.

Comment: Constructors should generally only have variable declarations in them. The rest is up to the methods.

Comment: I was using GLOBALS just for debugging purposes because I needed to know if it was entering the constructor without breaking anything else.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Side note: read up on "SQL injection" and "Prepared statements".

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You named your function `__contruct()` where it should be `__construct()`. This is a very common error, you should probably get some sleep.

Comment: To think that this "typo" has kept me stuck for the last 3 weeks. ^_^;;  I think I'm going to call it the typo from hell.  Live and learn.  Thanks for your help.  I'm glad to be moving forward again, and at least I learned a lot about debugging PHP in the process.

Comment: Aye, if a function is not being called when it's supposed to (either on object instantiation or on a regular function call), assuming no errors are logged, it's very likely you've just mistyped the function name (either on the call or on the function declaration). Good luck next time :D

Comment: Just spent almost 5 minutes staring at those two above and wondering... What is different. If you're as burnt out as me right now, the first one is missing the `s`.

Comment: @Tom: I think it's time for bed :)

Comment: I just spent 2 hours learning what I already knew about `OOP` to have this exact issue. +1

Comment: @JimFell everyone've been there. Try to use a text editor that sets a different color for magic methods. In my case, I use Sublime Text 2 and it gets easier to see a typo because of the color scheme.

Comment: Funny, I accidentally make the same type over and over again...

Comment: @Julian: Get a better IDE.

Comment: I had the same problem... reviewed my code and found the same typo hahahaha. Thank you :)