# PHP class to count words from a txt file

Tags: php, oop

I have a snippet of code that will count the words from a given .txt file, but for some reasons I am getting the following error and no results are given. I don't understand what's wrong:

`Warning: arsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php-oop/class.wordcounter.php on line 20`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php-oop/class.wordcounter.php on line 21`

```
<?php // index.php
    include_once("class.wordcounter.php");
    $wc = new WordCounter("words.txt");
    $wc->count(WordCounter::DESC);
?>


<?php //class.wordcounter.php

class WordCounter {

    const ASC = 1;
    const DESC = 2;

    private $words;

    function __contruct($filename) {
        $file_content = file_get_contents($filename);
        $this->words = (array_count_values(str_word_count(strtolower($file_content),1)));

    }

    public function count($order) {
        if ($order == self::ASC)
            asort($this->words);
        else if ($order == self::DESC)
            arsort($this->words);
        foreach ($this->words as $key => $val)
            echo $key . " = " . $val . "<br/>";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: This error means: `$this->words` is not array, but should be.

Comment: try var_dump on $this->words inside the constructor; i'm assuming $file_content is empty?

Comment: I tried to check if the file is not taken, but it is and I checked if it is returned as an array and it is..So what? I am on MAMP

Comment: Why someone voted -1?? I think that is a pretty useful code once debugged

Comment: you misspelled the __construct method

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Constructor Not Called Upon Instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733690/php-constructor-not-called-upon-instantiation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the bug, the `__construct` method was misspelled!

Here is the corrected code and it works:

```
<?php // index.php
    include_once("class.wordcounter.php");
    $wc = new WordCounter("words.txt");
    $wc->count(WordCounter::DESC);
?>


<?php //class.wordcounter.php

class WordCounter {

    const ASC = 1;
    const DESC = 2;

    private $words;

    function __construct($filename) {
        $file_content = file_get_contents($filename);
        $this->words = (array_count_values(str_word_count(strtolower($file_content),1)));

    }

    public function count($order) {
        if ($order == self::ASC)
            asort($this->words);
        else if ($order == self::DESC)
            arsort($this->words);
        foreach ($this->words as $key => $val)
            echo $key . " = " . $val . "<br/>";
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script is not being able of getting the file specified. Please try with an absolute URL and let me know if it works.

Change this line:

```
$wc = new WordCounter("http://your_domain/your_path/words.txt");
```

Comment: I tried to call the file directly with file_get_contents without passing via the Class and it works. So it's not a matter of path I think.

Comment: Try using file() instead of file_get_contents() to retrieve the content of the file as an array: http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Btw, try debugging by adding var_dump($file_content) after $file_content = file_get_contents($filename); and post the output in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `file_get_contents()` is actually returning something? Just because you see the file there doesn't mean that PHP can definitely access it.

Comment: I am sure I tried to call the file directly via file_get_contents without using the Class and it works just fine :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$no_of_words = 0;
str_replace(" ","",file_get_contents("/filename.txt"),$no_of_words);
echo $no_of_words;
?>
```