# PHP Constructor not called in class

Tags: php

Setting the a property in a `class` constructor doesn't work for me, using PHP 7.0.17.

```
class T
{
  public $property;
    function __contruct()
    {
        $this->property = "Test";
        print "I'm called :)";
    }
}

$t1 = new T();
print_r($t1);
```

*t.php*

When I run the code via `php t.php`, I get:

```
T Object
(
    [property] => 
)
```

Obviously, I would expect `I'm called :)` to printed to the terminal and the property be set to `Test`. As illustrated [in this example on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#example-188)

It's a very simple issue but I really need another pair of eyes on this.

Comment: `$this->property`, not `$this->$property`

Comment: `$this->$property` -> note that you have `$` twice. Is that intended?

Comment: Also, `__construct`, not `__contruct`

Comment: @MarkBaker and @Mjh, when I remove the `$` from `->$property` I get the same result. I'll update the question.

Comment: @roberto06 YEES! I love your eyes. I've been starring at this issue for too long.

Comment: Develop with a tool that has code-inspection (PHPStrom, Netbeans) or on comand line validate your syntax with `php -l t.php`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8733690/3933332

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter you should know by now that you should not edit your question with the answer you are given, as it invalidates content.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The issue was that I typed `__contruct` and **not** `__construct`. `$this->$property` throws a syntax error and is therefore easy to catch. I did not change the real issue here.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions `php -l` does **not** catch this type of errors. Because `__contruct` is legal, even though I meant `__construct`.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter I know, and you are right, it is not the biggest issue, but it doesn't change that it was the initial question, and is mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Ok, thats right, then use and tool with code-inspection and you will always get an typehint if you try to make an class method that is underscored. And my comments (no answer) was just a tip for better developing.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I'm using vscode. If you know of an extension that can help me catch these type of errors, I will appreciate it.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Do it the other way around , make a code snippet template the difens a class with all magich methods,  so you ill never make that typo again https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets   and by the way this `$this->$property = 'abc'` is not a error at all. You can use variables to access properties. if  `$property='myvar'` then `$this->$property='abc';` will do `$this->myvar='abc';`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions You're right! You can access properties via variables. I thought it was only variable functions and array indexes that had this property. I'll look into using templates - it's probably a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$this->$property` to `$this->property`

Change `contruct` to `construct`

```
class T
{
  public $property;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->property = "Test";
        print "I'm called :)";
    }
}

$t1 = new T();
print_r($t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the properties of a class with object (including `this`), you dont have to use the `$` again.

That is

```
$this->property='something';
```

From outside the class,

```
$t = new T();
$t->property='something';
```